# CoffeeScript (Node.js) IoC Aliasing

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, inversion-of-control, alias, service-locator

This may be a tad long but I've hit a slight design barrier.

For starters I've created an IoC (inversion-of-control) containing specializing in service locator and not dependency injection. (Also this is written in coffee-script running on node.js w/ harmony proxies enabled)

The container is pretty straight forward. You create a new instance of a container object and store that variable globally, or locally.

```
Context    = require('ettore').Context
AppContext = new Context()
App = AppContext.create 'App'
```

In this case, I've also implemented a context object that manages sub-contexts (though i'll probably take that out)

To store information within the container you use the following:

```
App.set 'Namespace.Controller.Action', 'Value goes here'
App.set 'Namespace.Controller.Action.Index', 'Value goes here x2'
```

This works perfectly and resolving a dependency is just as simple (also have the ability to use an async approach)

```
App.resolve 'Namespace.Controller.Action' # 'Value goes here'
App.get 'Namespace.Controller.Action' # 'Value goes here'
```

This is a good system but requires boilerplate code and it's required to go through the IoC container up-front and not "behind the scenes". So I started implementing an alias system that would make the previous code work like:

```
NM = App.alias "Namespace"
NM.Controller.Action # 'Value goes here'
```

This works using harmony proxies provided by the V8 engine (with fallback to a library use).

**The Problem**

The problem is simple but yet complex at the same time (unless I'm over thinking this...). Again with the previous set examples we have two components:

Namespace.Controller.Action
   Namespace.Controller.Action.Index

My system works flawlessly with the first example, returning a resolved dependency if one has been found. Otherwise it will either emit an error or return false. The problem comes with knowing if you should return a dependency or another proxy object so they can continue down the line.

To make this clear:

The system goes object by object through the proxy and returns (typically) the same proxy object. This allows you to have long namespaces or a naming scheme of your choosing. If you call the following statement:

Namespace.Controller.Action

It will go through the system 2 times. One for the controller, and another for the action. The problem is that you honestly don't know if there's another object attached to the current one. (e.g Are they calling .Index after Action?)

Right now i've implemented a sort of promise system that isn't so great. For the current "loop", it will check if a dependency exists for the fully qualified name. If so then it will add a mixing method called "then" apart from the ordinary proxy.

So if you have the following namespaces:

```
Namespace.Controller.Action
Namespace.Controller.Action.Index
```

To access the contents of the "Namespace.Controller.Action" component you must use a promise as there's a "conflict" in naming.

```
Namespace.Controller.Action.then ->
   @get # 'Value goes here'
Namespace.Controller.Action.Index # 'Value goes here x2'
```

**Question**

Is there a better way to achieve or fix this problem? I'm getting closer with time but it all seems a little hacky at times.

**Source Code**
For obvious reasons, I didn't post the full source code here as it's quite long. The main code for the aliasing and container is found here: https://github.com/TheHydroImpulse/Ettore/blob/master/lib/Container.coffee

An example file, using the same principles here (aliasing) is found: https://github.com/TheHydroImpulse/Ettore/blob/master/examples/alias.coffee

NOTE: If you need me to explain something in more detail just let me know... It's kind of a weird problem to describe.